# How to add a line to a barplot for every name in my data frame?

Tags: ggplot2

I am struggling with finding a way to add a line to every x variable which I define as name in my df by using ggplot on a barplot with multiple columns. I also tried to do this in Excel, just to se if it was possible in VBA, however, I did not manage to do it in excel neither and when trying to do it in R, I get the same problem (therefore I am actually not sure whether or not it is possible).

The barplot I have made using ggplot is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNei9.png)

with the following code used

```
enter code here df_bar <- as.data.frame(
               rbind(
c('g1', 0.945131015,      1.083188828,                 1.040164338,                 
1.115716593,                 0.947886795),
c('g2', 1.393211286,      1.264193745,                 1.463434395,                 
       1.298126006,                 1.112718796),
c('g3', 1.509976099,      1.450923745,                 1.455102201,                 
     1.280102338,                 1.462689245),
  c('g4', 1.591697668,      1.326292649,                 1.767207296,                 
   1.623619341,                 2.528108183),
c('g5', 2.625114848,      2.164050167,                 2.092843287,                 
 2.301950359,                 2.352736806)
  )
 )  

 colnames(df_bar)<-c('interval', 'lvl3.Mellem.Høj',    'lvl1.Lav',     'TOM',         
       ',lvl4.Høj',                 'lvl2.Lav.Mellem')

        df_bar <- melt(df_bar, id.vars = "interval",
           variable.name = "name", 
           value.name = "value")
       df_line <- as.data.frame(
          rbind(
           c('g1', 0.945131015 * 2,    1.083188828 * 2,                 1.040164338 * 2,                 
         1.115716593 * 2,                 0.947886795 * 2),
         c('g2', 1.393211286 * 2,    1.264193745 * 2,                 1.463434395 * 2,                 
         1.298126006 * 2,                 1.112718796 * 2),
         c('g3', 1.509976099 * 2,    1.450923745 * 2,                 1.455102201 * 2,                 
        1.280102338 * 2,                 1.462689245 * 2),
       c('g4', 1.591697668 * 2,    1.326292649 * 2,                 1.767207296 * 2,                 
       1.623619341 * 2,                 2.528108183 * 2),
       c('g5', 2.625114848 * 2,    2.164050167 * 2,                 2.092843287 * 2,                 
       2.301950359 * 2,                 2.352736806 * 2)
    )
     ) 

     colnames(df_line)<-c('interval', 'lvl3.Mellem.Høj',   'lvl1.Lav',     'TOM',         
      ',lvl4.Høj',                 'lvl2.Lav.Mellem')

   df_line <- melt(df_line, id.vars = "interval",
            variable.name = "name", 
            value.name = "sd")


   df <- inner_join(df_bar,df_line)

   ggplot(df, aes(fill=interval))  + 
   geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
   theme_bw()
```

However, when trying to add the sd column in my data frame to the plot, where the code is

```
enter code here ggplot(df, aes(fill=interval))  + 
                geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
                geom_line(aes(x=name, y=sd, group=interval),stat="identity") +
                theme_bw()
```

I get the following plot

[enter image description here][2]

which is not want I want since I want something like this

```
[enter image description here][3]
```

i.e. I want to get a line for every column in df_line. The code I have written creates a line for every row in df_line which is not the desired result. I hope this makes sense and that you have an idea what I might be able to do.

Thanks.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFWM3.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWOBH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` to separate out the plots by name, which will make it easier to plot your desired lines. Keep in mind that in your dataset, your SDs are larger than your values, so any `geom_line` or `geom_smooth` will go above your `geom_bar`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  mutate(sd = as.numeric(sd)) %>%
  mutate(interval = as.factor(interval)) %>%
  mutate(name = as.factor(name)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = interval, y = value, fill = interval), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = interval, y = sd, group = 1), 
              color = "black", size = .75) +
  facet_grid(~name, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("Interval") + ylab("Value") +
  labs(caption = "Black line indicates standard deviation.")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It worked. However, would it also be possible to add a second y-axis for the geom_line? I tried to do it by using scale_y_continous, but I couldn't make it work..

Comment: I actually made it work but it doesn't auto fit the other scale as I want it to. Is this possible?

Comment: If this is a separate issue from your original question, you should make a new StackOverflow post with another minimal reproducible example.